# RichTextBox как пользоваться

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как пользоваться RichTextBox? Как вставлять текст и менять его внешний вид(цвет или задний фон отдельных слов и т.п.) в XAML? и в c# если не сложно. или ссылку киньте плз.

Comment: Вам следует воспользоваться поиском, так как ваш вопрос общенаправленный. При обычном запросе в гугл можно найти такое:
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/richtextbox-control/

Если же вы хотите решить конкретную проблему, уточните вопрос

Comment: @alladuh Мне надо вставить текст состоящий из чисел(как пример "01  02  03  04 ... 49") и его редактировать из c# кода -> передавать новый текст где определенные числа имеют иной цвет, красный к примеру или в рамку заключено и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про цвет я не понял. Что касается редактирования текста, то можно так:

```
<RichTextBox Margin="10" x:Name="myRich">
         <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph FontSize="36">Hello, world!</Paragraph>
            <Paragraph FontStyle="Italic" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" Foreground="Gray">Thanks to the RichTextBox control, this FlowDocument is completely editable!</Paragraph>
         </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

А затем в коде создать

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(myRich.Document.ContentStart, myRich.Document.ContentEnd);
```

И через свойства у `textRange` обращаться или ко всему тексту или к определённым параграфам.

Comment: Спасибо, а вот что означает <FlowDocument> и можно ли обращаться через textRange к определенному слову а не тексту, там же есть  TextPointer позиция, можно ли ей задать позицию посередине текста а не в конце или начале?

Comment: @MrBorman вот информация по FlowDocument: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/15.php

Не стесняйтесь искать информацию, это же почти первая ссылка по запросу - flowdocument wpf

Comment: @MrBorman Думаю, что к определённому слову просто так обратиться нельзя. Но весь текст можно разбить с помощью метода Split(): textRange.Text.Split(), внтури метода передаются разделители.
Например, если у вас строка вида "01 02 03 04", то в методе можно указать пробел - Split(' '). этот метод возвращает массив строк. Вот с ним вы уже можете работать